# how to load a new tile view where the source is an array of objects from the json file

Tags: sapui5, tile

I have `StandrdTiles` with JSON (example below). My problem is connected with JSON file structure and path to tile collection (is defined in XML view). I'm try to have functionality like: If you click on tile, new view will be load with another group of tiles where model will be selected array (based on some parameter) from JSON file. So, I want to load new view clicking on tile where model is selected by array name with objects (`tile0 --> view + data0 collection; tile1 --> view + data1 collection`).

It's possible to dynamically change **tiles** value in XML view from controller?

```
<TileContainer
    id="container"
    tiles="{}" <-- how to change value from controller before loading data?
...
```

data.json

```
{
  "TileCollection": [{
    "data0": [{
      "icon": "sap-icon://inbox",
      "number": "1",
      "title": "Lorem ipsum",
      "info": "Lorem ipsum",
      "infoState": "Error"
    }, {
      "icon": "sap-icon://technical-object",
      "number": "2",
      "title": "Lorem ipsum",
      "info": "Lorem ipsum",
      "infoState": "Success"
    }, {
      "icon": "sap-icon://inbox",
      "number": "3",
      "numberUnit": "",
      "title": "Lorem ipsum",
      "info": "Lorem ipsum"
    }]
  }, {
    "data1": [{
      "icon": "sap-icon://inbox",
      "number": "4",
      "title": "Lorem ipsum",
      "info": "Lorem ipsum",
      "infoState": "Error"
    }, {
      "icon": "sap-icon://technical-object",
      "number": "5",
      "title": "Lorem ipsum",
      "info": "Lorem ipsum",
      "infoState": "Success"
    }, {
      "icon": "sap-icon://inbox",
      "number": "6",
      "numberUnit": "",
      "title": "Lorem ipsum",
      "info": "Lorem ipsum"
    }]
  }]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a master-detail type scenario, where you can make use of routings. Here is a **[Detailed example](https://embed.plnkr.co/bc67DpXKrJfszyWQTuDm/)** using `SAPUI5` routings in a `Full-Screen` Application. I will try and summarize as much as possible...

In your **JSON**, assign an **ID** to each Tile and assuming "data..." are the contents of each tiles view, if you need to add content to the tile they can go in the same level as its ID, the IDs will be used as patterns for the routings:

```js
{
  "TileCollection": [{
    "homeId": 0,
    "homeIcon": "sap-icon://waiver",
    "homeType": "Create",
    "homeNumber": 160,
    "homeNumberUnit": "£",
    "homeTitle": "Home-Waiver",
    "homeInfo": "Lorem ipsum",
    "homeInfoState": "Success",
    "home0Data": [{
      "home0Id": 0,
      "home0Icon": "sap-icon://loan",
      "home0Type": "Create",
      "home0Number": "0-1",
      "home0NumberUnit": "T",
      "home0Title": "Home-LevelOne-Loan",
      "home0Info": "Lorem ipsum",
      "home0InfoState": "Success",
      "home0Properties": [{
        "propId": 0,
        "text0": "Home-LevelTwo-Visit SAP Homepage 01",
        "url": "http://www.sap.com",
        "icon": "sap-icon://menu"
      }, {
        "propId": 1,
        "text0": "Home-LevelTwo-Visit SAP Homepage 02",
        "url": "http://www.sap.com",
        "icon": "sap-icon://menu"
      }, {
        "propId": 2,
        "text0": "Home-LevelTwo-Visit SAP Homepage 03",
        "url": "http://www.sap.com",
        "icon": "sap-icon://menu"
      }]
    }, {
      "home0Id": 1,
      "home0Icon": "sap-icon://money-bills",
      "home0Type": "Create",
      "home0Number": "1-1",
      "home0NumberUnit": "T",
      "home0Title": "Home-LevelOne-Money",
      "home0Info": "Lorem ipsum",
      "home0InfoState": "Success",
      "home0Properties": [{
        "propId": 0,
        "text0": "Home-LevelTwo-Visit SAP Homepage 11",
        "url": "http://www.sap.com",
        "icon": "sap-icon://menu"
      }, {
        "propId": 1,
        "text0": "Home-LevelTwo-Visit SAP Homepage 12",
        "url": "http://www.sap.com",
        "icon": "sap-icon://menu"
      }, {
        "propId": 2,
        "text0": "Home-LevelTwo-Visit SAP Homepage 13",
        "url": "http://www.sap.com",
        "icon": "sap-icon://menu"
      }]
    }]
  }, {
    "homeId": 1,
    "homeIcon": "sap-icon://wallet",
    "homeType": "Create",
    "homeNumber": 200,
    "homeNumberUnit": "£",
    "homeTitle": "Home-Wallet",
    "homeInfo": "Lorem ipsum",
    "homeInfoState": "Warning",
    "home0Data": [{
      "home0Id": 0,
      "home0Icon": "sap-icon://receipt",
      "home0Type": "Create",
      "home0Number": "0-1",
      "home0NumberUnit": "T",
      "home0Title": "Home-LevelOne-Receipt",
      "home0Info": "Lorem ipsum",
      "home0InfoState": "Warning",
      "home0Properties": [{
        "propId": 0,
        "text0": "Home-LevelTwo-Visit SAP Homepage 11",
        "url": "http://www.sap.com",
        "icon": "sap-icon://menu"
      }, {
        "propId": 1,
        "text0": "Home-LevelTwo-Visit SAP Homepage 12",
        "url": "http://www.sap.com",
        "icon": "sap-icon://menu"
      }, {
        "propId": 2,
        "text0": "Home-LevelTwo-Visit SAP Homepage 13",
        "url": "http://www.sap.com",
        "icon": "sap-icon://menu"
      }]
    }]
  }, {
    "homeId": 2,
    "homeIcon": "sap-icon://credit-card",
    "homeType": "Create",
    "homeNumber": 350,
    "homeNumberUnit": "£",
    "homeTitle": "Home-Credit-Card",
    "homeInfo": "Lorem ipsum",
    "homeInfoState": "Error",
    "home0Data": [{
      "home0Id": 0,
      "home0Icon": "sap-icon://account",
      "home0Type": "Create",
      "home0Number": "3-1",
      "home0NumberUnit": "£",
      "home0Title": "Home-LevelOne-Account",
      "home0Info": "Lorem ipsum",
      "home0InfoState": "Error",
      "home0Properties": [{
        "propId": 0,
        "text0": "Home-LevelTwo Visit SAP Homepage 31",
        "url": "http://www.sap.com",
        "icon": "sap-icon://menu"
      }, {
        "propId": 1,
        "text0": "Home-LevelTwo Visit SAP Homepage 32",
        "url": "http://www.sap.com",
        "icon": "sap-icon://menu"
      }, {
        "propId": 2,
        "text0": "Home-LevelTwo Visit SAP Homepage 33",
        "url": "http://www.sap.com",
        "icon": "sap-icon://menu"
      }]
    }]
  }]
}
```

In your **Initial View**:

```html
<TileContainer id="container" tileDelete="handleTileDelete" tiles="{/TileCollection}">
  <StandardTile icon="{homeIcon}" type="{homeType}" number="{homeNumber}" numberUnit="{homeNumberUnit}" title="{homeTitle}" info="{homeInfo}" infoState="{homeInfoState}" press="onSelectionChange" />
</TileContainer>
```

In its **Controller**, when a tile is clicked in the initial view,  it should bind the data contents:

```js
onSelectionChange: function(oEvent) {
  this.getOwnerComponent().getRouter().navTo("levelOne", {
    levelOneID: oEvent.getSource().getBindingContext().getProperty("homeId")
  });
}
```

For the second set of tiles in its **View**:

```html
<TileContainer id="container1" tiles="{home0Data}">
  <StandardTile icon="{home0Icon}" type="{home0Type}" number="{home0Id}" numberUnit="{home0NumberUnit}" title="{home0Title}" info="{home0Info}" infoState="{home0InfoState}" press="onSelectionChange" />
</TileContainer>
```

Second **Controller**:

```js
_onRouteMatched: function(oEvent) {
    this._levelOneID = oEvent.getParameter("arguments").levelOneID;
    this.getView().bindElement("/TileCollection/" + this._levelOneID);
  },

  onSelectionChange: function(oEvent) {
    var sLevelTwoID = oEvent.getSource().getBindingContext().getProperty("home0Id");

    this.getOwnerComponent().getRouter().navTo("levelTwo", {
      levelOneID: this._levelOneID,
      levelTwoID: sLevelTwoID
    });
  }
```

And most importantly, your **manifest** should contain the pattern of the routing, this will update the url so that the contents in the right hierarchy are displayed in View:

```js
"routing": {
  "config": {
    "routerClass": "sap.m.routing.Router",
    "viewType": "XML",
    "viewPath": "sap.otuniyi.sample",
    "controlId": "rootControl",
    "controlAggregation": "pages",
    "transition": "slide",
    "bypassed": {
      "target": ["home", "notFound"]
    },
    "async": true
  },
  "routes": [{
    "pattern": "",
    "name": "apphome",
    "target": "home"
  }, {
    "name": "levelOne",
    "pattern": "TileCollection/:levelOneID:",<-- this changes the value in the controller before loading the data
    "target": ["home", "levelOne"]
  }, {
    "name": "levelTwo",
    "pattern": "TileCollection/:levelOneID:/home0Properties/:levelTwoID:", <-- and this
    "target": ["levelOne", "levelTwo"]
  }],
  "targets": {
    "home": {
      "viewId": "home",
      "viewName": "Homepage",
      "viewLevel": 0
    },
    "notFound": {
      "viewId": "notFound",
      "viewName": "NotFound",
      "transition": "show"
    },
    "levelOne": {
      "viewName": "LevelOne",
      "viewLevel": "1"
    },
    "levelTwo": {
      "viewName": "LevelTwo",
      "viewLevel": "2"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Olayinka Otuniyi! You have right it's something almost like master-detail. I will add some details to describe my task. I want to create some kind of menu based on standard tiles. If you press a tile you will be redirected to some URL or you will open/load new view with standard tiles and bind different objects from different array: data0 - data1 or data0 - data2 etc.). It's possible to get path to array by array name? It's good direction?

Comment: Something like this? **[See this example](https://embed.plnkr.co/Z2UGpqb3Ok8MdafmLCHb/)**, I can update the answer if this is similar to what you're describing :). View and navigate in separate window.

Comment: Yes, like your example! Thank you very very very much :)

Comment: @DirtyFrank perfect! I have updated my initial answer, if it helped please mark it as answered :)  **[To accept an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)**

Comment: One more question :) I have in controller: 

onAfterRendering : function(oEvent) {
var viewTitle = oEvent.getSource().getBindingContext().getProperty("parentTitle");
var oPage = this.byId("levelOnePage").setTitle(viewTitle);
}

It's working fine, but how it execute every time when I view a page (view)

Comment: I found solution.

Comment: Apologies for the late response, I think you would have to add that same code to every controller per view but if you've found a different solution that's perfect too :) @DirtyFrank