# SAP UI5 NetworkGraph (custom positions; views; routing)

Tags: sapui5

I want to create using NetworkGraph a graph/schema. Every node will have two function onclick: open external URL or load new data (from JSON file/database) and generate new graph based on new data in new view. This question is very similiar to one my previous post ([how to load a new tile view where the source is an array of objects from the json file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52468933/how-to-load-a-new-tile-view-where-the-source-is-an-array-of-objects-from-the-jso)).

Because I have no expirience with NetworkGraph I need some help, tips, etc..

1. How to create graph with custom positions of nodes x,y (example below) [image: example of graph]
2. How to solve routing and views? (I don't now how many childs will be) Dynamically?

Thanks in advance.